# How to use Meta's SAM (Segment Anything Model) in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, onnx, sam

I'm trying to use SAM in a project that already uses tensorflow for another model. As SAM uses pytorch I have to choose which model gets the GPU. So, I'd like a way to use SAM with tensorflow.

I tried reducing tensorflow and pytorch memory assigned from the GPU, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of the Segment Anything model in Keras Core so you can now run the model in TensorFlow and JAX: https://github.com/tirthasheshpatel/segment_anything_keras

Here's a guide you might want to check out: https://github.com/tirthasheshpatel/segment_anything_keras/blob/main/Segment_Anything_Automatic_Mask_Generator_Demo.ipynb